# Phalcon: css work only in indexAction

Tags: php, css, phalcon

I'm a beginner developer and I'm using the Phalcon to develop a small app.
I have problem with the pages that are not of indexAction. For example if I have a editAction action that aponter to your view, this view does not loading the css.
Now if I change the name to edit.phtml index.phtml the css loads perfectly.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use root relative paths to your CSS (and JavaScript) files. I.e.

`"css/style/css"` is relative path, but

`"/css/style.css"` is root relative path.

Comment: MilanG, my link css is here   <br/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/locastyle.css"> <br/> this make me nervous.... for example: if i use http://localhost/teste/cliente, my page load perfectly, but, if i use http://localhost/teste/cliente/index, my page lost all formats.  <br/> How i resolve this <br/> Sorry for my english.

Comment: Try changing it to .... href="/public/css/localstyle.css....
Just add slash sign in front of "public" path part.